# Woocommerce not showing price excluding tax on product detail page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, tax

I have 2 products on the site and using tax on them. One product has priced $38.00 and showing price excluding tax on product detail page that is $34.55. The other product has $88.00 price but on the detail page, it is showing $88.00 instead it should show price excluding tax i.e $80.00.

Here are the Tax settings I am using:
[image]

When adding product I set **Tax status** as **Taxable** and set **Tax class** as **Standard**. Both the products have same settings but one is showing price excluding tax and other is showing price including tax on the detail page. I don't understand what is the issue.

**UPDATE**

Here is the price configuration of both the products:
The product whose price is not showing excluding Tax:

[image]

The product whose price is showing excluding Tax:
[image]

Can anyone help me to get this issue fixed?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post your 2 product prices configurations (backend product edit) ?

Comment: I updated my post above. Kindly check.